# Azure Connect-AzAccount in runbook with managed identity fails

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-managed-identity, azure-runbook

I am trying to execute a runbook in an automation account within azure.

I have set a managed identity following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation), then i issue the following in my runbook:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription Subscription1
```

As instructed [here](https://Connect-AzAccount%20-Identity%20Set-AzContext%20-Subscription%20Subscription1)

But i get the following error:

```
Set-AzContext : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
 At line:134 char:1
 + Set-AzContext -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionId
```

I pass the tenantId and subscriptionId through as parameters, and have written them out to confirm they are correct.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

**Update**

I have added the `owner` role to the system assigned managed identity and now it seems to get the connection ok with Dilly B's suggestion below:

```
$null = Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $managedIdentity).context  # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity

$connectionResult = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionId -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

however when i do:

```
$virtualMachine = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $virtualMachineName
```

I now get the following error:

```
Get-AzVM : The client '****************' with object id '*****************' does 
 not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/******************/resourceGroups/***************/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/************' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
 ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailed
 ErrorMessage: The client '******************' with object id '*****************************' 
 does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/******************/resourceGroups/**************/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/**************' or the scope is invalid.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find the sample code below. Hope this helps!

```
$subscription = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
$identity = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"

$null = Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $identity).context  # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity

$connectionResult = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

Comment: Thanks Dilly B - tried this but I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @abinitio Make sure you have enabled your system assigned identity turned on and right permissions assigned  -> Go to Automation Accounts, select your account, go to Identity, and under the System Assigned tab switch Status to On.

Comment: Hi DIlly - I had the status switch on. I have added the owner role to the identity, and now it looks like the connection is working (or at least doesnt through an error when i do `Set-AzContext`) but when I try and do a read on a virtual machine  in the same subscription I get the error above.

Comment: Could you please post your command and followed by the error.

Comment: I managed to get this sorted - I hadn't assigned the contributor role to the managed identity.

Comment: Glad to know, I also stated this on my previous comment. Please mark an answer - If you find this helpful. Thanks!

Comment: in this code - whats is the $identity of the user managed identity. I can see the Subscription ID, the Client ID and the Object (principal) ID but I dont know which refers to the "AccountId" parameter?

Comment: @m_finn - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-manage-user-assigned-managed-identities?pivots=identity-mi-methods-azp after creating one, it can be assigned to azure resources

Comment: Thanks a million. This has fixed the same issue I have been facing. Upvoting it. To add to your solution, the value for $identity, in your code solution, should be "ClientID" of the "User Managed Identity" . Guess it might be useful for some who do not have much system knowledge like me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have up-to-date modules for Az.Accounts (2.10.2), Az.Resources (6.3.0), Az.Automation (1.8.0).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules

Comment: Thanks Ken - I have previously imported this runbook and tried to run it, but it needs a run as account. I am trying to remove run as account from my automation account and switch to managed identity instead. Trying to output the versions with `$azAccount=Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Accounts` `Write-Output $azAccount` gives the error Get-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'Az.Accounts'.

Comment: I can't seem to update the modules in the portal either, as the version i have is the highest on offer ( Az.Accounts (2.8.0), Az.Resources (6.0.0), Az.Automation (1.7.3))